# ways to select values by keys list?

Tags: redis, high-load

For example I have key structure `entity:product:[id]` where id - is an integer `[0-n]`

So I can use this `keys entity:product:*` but I don't how much load does this query to the redis server.

Another solution is

1. Create one list key that will store Ids of the entity:products.

   ```
   RPUSH entity:products:ids 1 
   RPUSH entity:products:ids 2
   RPUSH entity:products:ids 3
   RPUSH entity:products:ids 4
   ```
2. And then (pseudo-code)

   ```
   entityProducts = redis.LRANGE('entityLproducts:ids, 0, -1)

   foreach (entityProducts as id)
   {
       redis.GET('entity:product:' + id)
   }
   ```

What is the better way? What will be faster and what will do less load to the redis server?